# SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true

Tags: mysql, grails, jdbc

When my grails application faces high load, I encounter some SQLException :
java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true

This problem appears only when the number of connection on the application raises.

I'm using grails 1.2.2 and mysql 5.1

Does anybody already faces such kind of problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried to switch off autocommit?

Comment: grails automatically manage autocommit mode (autocommit is on if you are in Controller, in a Service, transaction is used). Actually, the problem occurs only when I get a high load on my application.

Comment: oops, sorry, i was though that it's a connection option

Comment: You can use transactions in controllers too by putting all code that accesses the DB inside a closure `SomeDomainClass.withTransaction { // this code will run inside a transaction}`